# Is it okay and acceptable to leave intern job after probation period?

Tags: career-development, internship, probation

Last month, I applied job as an intern to the company. However, I can not do fulltime intern because I still pursue my degree. I can only work for 2–3 days a week. So, my employer said that he will give me a probation for about 2 weeks. After that if the probation goes well I can continue to the employment offer.

The problem is, I found that the circumstances around doing a job and completing my degree is not a easy thing to do it together. And there is a condition in the company that did not suitable for me. So, I decide to leave after the probation period end.

Comment: Probation periods goes two ways. It is for the employer to see if you suit the company, but also for you to see if the company suits you. This counts for 'real jobs' as well not just for intern positions. Clearly not everyone will be happy, but this is always better then leaving shortly after the probation period.

Comment: Make sure you check the relative rules governing probations and notice periods that apply to you as well as anything in your employment contract if you have one. Sometimes they mean that you can only easily resign *during* the probation period. And why aren't you just telling your employer right now that it won't work out for you before he invests more time in you?

Comment: It's okay to leave after the probation period.  It's okay to leave during the probation period.  Very few countries still have actual slavery nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Probation period is for **both** parties to realise if the role is correct for the new person and the new person is correct for the company. So if you don't want to stay, it's perfectly fine to leave within this period, as that is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's up to you.  It's important to finish your degree and if the company really likes you they will likely want to hire you after your degree is finished too.

If you can't do full time work and get a degree, then perhaps you can ask them to continue part time until you graduate?  If not you can always leave and re-apply when you finish with your degree.  Noone should fault you for leaving to finish you degree first.